# Python 3 converting escaped unicode characters in strings into the characters themselves

Tags: python-3.x, unicode, character-encoding, unicode-escapes

I've got some data stored as strings that contains both unicode characters (e.g., `ñ`) and unicode escape sequences (e.g., `\u00F1`). I would like to do a string-to-string transformation that converts the escape sequences into the corresponding unicode characters. For example, if the string is `s = r'\u00F1ñ'`, I would like the output to be `'ññ'`.

The closest I've found so far is `s.encode().decode('unicode-escape')`: this converts the escape sequences, but mangles any unicode characters already present.

Please note that this question is for python 3.

Comment: For me, making it a regular string and using the default `utf8` encoding and decoding got the desired result.

Comment: Post code snippet? I've tried doing similar things...

Comment: Note that the r in front of the string is mandatory to get the correct representation of the data that I have.

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, the "unicode-escape" codec assumes Latin-1 for non-escaped characters. So you could try `s.encode('latin-1').decode('unicode-escape')`. Note: this will only work if your non-escaped characters have a codepoint below 256.

Comment: @lenz Indeed, that does it! `r'\u00F1ñ'.encode('latin-1').decode('unicode-escape')` returns `'ññ'` as desired. Feel free to make an answer to this extent so I can accept it.